# Using find() function on vector of vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

So I was trying to check whether a vector exists in a vector of vector or not, using the find() function but leetcode editor is showing compilation error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> res{{1, 2, 3}};
       if(std::find(res.begin(), res.end(), {1, -1, 0}) == res.end())
            res.push_back( {1, -1, 0} );  

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mention the vector type when calling `find`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res{{1, 2, 3}};  
    if (res.end() != std::find(
        res.begin(), res.end(), std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}))
    // An initializer list alone is not enough ^^^. in your code you use
    // {nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]} w/o mentioning what type to construct
    {
        std::cout << "vector{1, 2, 3} exists in res\n";
    }
}
```

this way it [works](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5a6c3585161d36)

The compilation error you're getting is probably this

```
error: no matching function for call to 
find(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator,
     std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator, 
     <brace-enclosed initializer list>)
```

i.e. the `find` method gets a plain initializer list.

TL;DR warning ahead:

The reason this is the case, is because in `find` iterator and value have [disparate types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );
```

so even after deducing the type of the iterator, the compiler can make no assumption on what the type of the value should be. The result is that even though a vector is constructible from an initializer list, the compiler has no clue what type to construct (it only knows the type it deduced). So, the init list is left as given and you have a compilation error.